# How to I install libuv and subsequently uWebSockets library on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, cmake, libuv, uwebsockets

I am trying to install few libraries that are required for cmake to build a project.

For successful build, cmake requires libuv and uWebSockets libraries to be installed:
https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets

I'm using MinGW gcc compiler (C:\msys64\mingw64) along with cmake.

However, during configuration cmake fails with the following errors:

```
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Error at examples/example1/CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_library):
[cmake]   Could not find UV_LIB using the following names: uv
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Now, I have downloaded the tar-balls from the above GitHub repo, but I am unable to understand where and how this is to be installed.

Comment: conan or vcpkg make this easier, otherwise follow the documentation that comes with the libraries

Comment: Is libuv in pacman? My guess is libuv is not installed. Edit: found it here [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-libuv](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-libuv)

Comment: `vcpkg install libuv uwebsockets --triplet=x64-windows`